# problem with mutating tables

Tags: oracle, select, triggers

I want to create trigger which will be fired after insert into some table, let`s say user.
In this trigger I want to select some records from table user, besides this one I insert to table, but then I receive error about mutating table. Is it possible to get records from this table?

Comment: Could you please post the error code?

Comment: ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Comment: Can you post the trigger code?  What does it want to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The autonomous transaction method is a workaround for this but doesn't address some other fundamental issues.

The major problem with this method is that when multiple modifications occur simultaneously to a table then the triggers that fire do not see the results of the other modifications. Therefore the results that you get from the trigger code can be incorrect.

For example, if you had a trigger on a table of "customer orders" that is intended to maintain a "customer total orders" column in the customer table, then two orders being placed at the same time cannot see each other. they each try to update the "customer total orders" with a total that excludes the other order.

For this and other reasons it is often considered bad practice to use triggers for business logic or to maintain other table data.

Answer (score 4):

To paraphrase Tom Kyke:

> when I hit a mutating table error, I've got a serious fatal flaw  in my logic.

This is a quite complex problem. There are multiple solutions to it, but the best is to change your logic so that you don't run into such errors.

A possible solution can be found [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:290416059674). There are some more discussions about this on Ask Tom, search for them and read them. You'll gain some very valuable knowledge.

Answer (score -5):

Make the trigger run in an autonomous transaction (separate transaction)

```
create or replace trigger xxx
before .... on .....

declare
.....

pragma autonomous transaction;
begin
.....your code.....
end;
```

Regards
K

Comment: -1 Autonmous Transactions should not be used lightly, or indeed for anything other than logging.  It is certainly bad advice to give to somebody without knowing the specifics of what they are trying to achieve.

Comment: Since you accepted this, I'm sure you were looking for a quick solution and you didn't know you could have used AT for the job. Not knowing about autonomous transactions, you probably also miss on other import things. My recommendation: even if you use an AT for now, do yourself a favor and read on other methods/opinions as well. See my answer below